# Focus "Stolen" by IFrame/Flash Ad

Tags: javascript, html, flash, iframe

I have a long page, which has some `IFrames` here and there. The page is an long "infinite-scroll" style page, where the `IFrames` are `Google DFP` banners. Inside `Google DFP`, there is my video player that plays content and ads (`Flash`, `VPAID` ads).

The issue is that once an ad gets loaded, it "steals" the focus so to speak. For instance, I may have been reading stuff on the bottom of the page, but immediately when an ad gets loaded, the page scrolls to the point where the ad is displayed.

This creates horrible UX. Since there is no code in my player to apply this focus, my guess is that the focus theft happens because of the `Google DFP` `IFrame` or because of the ad (the ad is a flash object that presumably can do things like inject `JavaScript` into the page in order to scroll).

Is there a way to guarantee that an `IFrame` an whatever runs inside of it does not steal focus from other elements on the page?

Comment: Hi orcaman- it sounds like dirty tactics to make the iframe 'scroll into view' so that viewability is higher for the ads shown...This is bad practice and I would find the bit of code running this script and try and avoid using it...If they are running javascript to do this, then realistically I don't think you'll be able to stop it without risking interference with other javascript on the page...